# Poor performance with Spark streaming, Kafka and multiple topics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Spark 2.1 + Kafka 0.10 + Spark streaming.

Batch duration is 30s.

I have 13 nodes, 2 brokers and I use 1 core per executor per topic/partition.
LocationStrategy is PreferConsistent.
When consuming 1 topic, no problem executors always process the same topic/partition (tested until 24 partitions).
When I add another topic, some executors used to process topic/partitions change from one batch to another.

When an executor processes the same topic/partition again (for example 3 batches after, so 1:30 after the previous processing) I get a deconnection of my KafkaConsumer because of request timeout (request.timeout.ms parameter) from the broker and then my new fetch query to the Kafka is blocked during 40s (request.timeout.ms parameter again).

```
2017-10-09 16:51:30.336 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class - Seeking to topic2-7 136136613
2017-10-09 16:51:30.336 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Seeking to offset 136136613 for partition topic2-7
2017-10-09 16:51:30.337 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Disconnecting from node 1005 due to request timeout.
2017-10-09 16:51:30.337 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler - Cancelled FETCH request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@30ea3352, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=1,api_version=2,correlation_id=25,client_id=consumer-1}, body={replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,topics=[{topic=topic2,partitions=[{partition=7,fetch_offset=136125064,max_bytes=1048576}]}]}), createdTimeMs=1507557031875, sendTimeMs=1507557031875) with correlation id 25 due to node 1005 being disconnected
2017-10-09 16:51:30.338 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1 - Fetch failed org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
2017-10-09 16:51:30.341 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater - Initialize connection to node 1006 for sending metadata request
2017-10-09 16:51:30.341 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node 1006 at broker001.domain.loc:9092.
2017-10-09 16:51:30.342 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-1006.bytes-sent
2017-10-09 16:51:30.342 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-1006.bytes-received
2017-10-09 16:51:30.342 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-1006.latency
2017-10-09 16:51:30.343 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Completed connection to node 1006
2017-10-09 16:51:30.343 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler - Cancelled FETCH request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@7d9e82c8, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=1,api_version=2,correlation_id=26,client_id=consumer-1}, body={replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,topics=[{topic=topic2,partitions=[{partition=7,fetch_offset=136136613,max_bytes=1048576}]}]}), createdTimeMs=1507557090341, sendTimeMs=0) with correlation id 26 due to node 1005 being disconnected
2017-10-09 16:51:30.343 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1 - Fetch failed org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
2017-10-09 16:51:30.343 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater - Sending metadata request {topics=[topic2]} to node 1006
2017-10-09 16:51:30.344 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler - Cancelled FETCH request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@4512b012, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=1,api_version=2,correlation_id=27,client_id=consumer-1}, body={replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,topics=[{topic=topic2,partitions=[{partition=7,fetch_offset=136136613,max_bytes=1048576}]}]}), createdTimeMs=1507557090343, sendTimeMs=0) with correlation id 27 due to node 1005 being disconnected
2017-10-09 16:51:30.344 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1 - Fetch failed org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
2017-10-09 16:51:30.344 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 3 to Cluster(nodes = [broker002.domain.loc:9092 (id: 1005 rack: null), broker001.domain.loc:9092 (id: 1006 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 14, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 13, leader = 1005, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1005,1006,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 12, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 11, leader = 1005, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1005,1006,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 10, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 9, leader = 1005, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1005,1006,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 8, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 7, leader = 1005, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1005,1006,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 6, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 5, leader = 1005, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1005,1006,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 4, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 3, leader = 1005, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1005,1006,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 2, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 1, leader = 1005, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1005,1006,], Partition(topic = topic2, partition = 0, leader = 1006, replicas = [1005,1006,], isr = [1006,1005,]])
2017-10-09 16:51:30.345 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler - Cancelled FETCH request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@4214186f, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=1,api_version=2,correlation_id=29,client_id=consumer-1}, body={replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,topics=[{topic=topic2,partitions=[{partition=7,fetch_offset=136136613,max_bytes=1048576}]}]}), createdTimeMs=1507557090344, sendTimeMs=0) with correlation id 29 due to node 1005 being disconnected
2017-10-09 16:51:30.345 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1 - Fetch failed org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
2017-10-09 16:51:42.942 DEBUG    [LeaseRenewer:hdfs_user@master001.domain.loc:8020]:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer - Lease renewer daemon for [] with renew id 1 executed
2017-10-09 16:52:00.293 DEBUG    [IPC Client (1926664485) connection to master001.domain.loc/10.0.10.1:8020 from hdfs_user]:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection - IPC Client (1926664485) connection to master001.domain.loc/10.0.10.1:8020 from hdfs_user: closed
2017-10-09 16:52:00.293 DEBUG    [IPC Client (1926664485) connection to master001.domain.loc/10.0.10.1:8020 from hdfs_user]:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection - IPC Client (1926664485) connection to master001.domain.loc/10.0.10.1:8020 from hdfs_user: stopped, remaining connections 0
2017-10-09 16:52:10.388 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler - Cancelled FETCH request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@4b954a27, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=1,api_version=2,correlation_id=30,client_id=consumer-1}, body={replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,topics=[{topic=topic2,partitions=[{partition=7,fetch_offset=136136613,max_bytes=1048576}]}]}), createdTimeMs=1507557090345, sendTimeMs=0) with correlation id 30 due to node 1005 being disconnected
2017-10-09 16:52:10.389 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1 - Fetch failed org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
2017-10-09 16:52:10.389 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node 1005 at broker002.domain.loc:9092.
2017-10-09 16:52:10.390 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Completed connection to node 1005
2017-10-09 16:52:10.397 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class - Polled [topic2-7]  2603
2017-10-09 16:52:10.398 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class - Getting local block broadcast_13
2017-10-09 16:52:10.398 DEBUG    [Executor task launch worker for task 315]:org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class - Level for block broadcast_13 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
```

What can I do to overcome this kind of problem?
Increase the request.timeout.ms parameter does not seem a good solution to me.

I have seen a parameter to disable cache for Kafka Consumers that could possibly solve this problem but it is available with Spark 2.2 and I can't go to Spark 2.2.

Only solution I can see for now should be to go back to a mono topic processing...

Thank you for your help!

**2017/10/18 : Update about this problem**
Switches of executors to process a topic/partition were due to data locality problems. For some topic/partition the executor needed to locally process data (locality level PROCESS_LOCAL) was not available so another executor was scheduled to process (locality level RACK_LOCAL), and this executor can be different from a batch to another.

My configuration was 1 core per executor.
I changed my configuration to allow 2 cores per executor and it is OK, all tasks are processed locally.
If a want to process 3 topics I have to change my configuration to 3 cores per executor (topics are uneven, 15 partitions for topic1, 3 for topic2 and 6 for topic 3 for example with 3 topics).

1 topic, 24 topic/partitions, 24 executors, 1 core per executors : OK
2 topics, 24 topic/partitions, 12 executors, 2 cores per executors : OK
3 topics, 24 topic/partitions, 8 executors, 3 cores per executors : OK
4 topics, 24 topic/partitions, 6 executors, 4 cores per executors : OK
6 topics, 24 topic/partitions, 4 executors, 6 cores per executors : KO

With 6 topics I run again into data locality problems.
What can I do to scale my Spark process with the number of topics?

Answer (score 0):

**Perform a *repartition* on your RDD**, it will trigger a shuffle and make sure every executor has almost equally local data (in-memory) to process.
For your 6 topics example, try to go with 12 executors, 2 cores per executor and `.repartition(48)`.
Call *repartition* before any transformation/action you make on the given RDD from the Kafka Consumer.

Note that *repartition* might have performance implications.